# Expressing numerical constraints using Prolog without CLP(FD)

Tags: prolog

```
ordering(A, B, C) :-
    integer(A),
    integer(B),
    integer(C),
    A > B,
    B > C,
    A > 0,
    10 > C.
```

is satisfied by `ordering(3,2,1).`. But when I leave one or more as variables `ordering(3,X,1).` it evaluates to `false`.

What am I missing?

Update: thanks for all the extensive answers. I’ve learned something from all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`integer/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=integer/1) fails if the argument is not an integer, for example if you pass an unbound variable.
I believe you should use CLP(FD) for these kind of tasks. Otherwise you may manually bind/test variables in some integer range, using [`between/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3) to set that range.

E.g.:

```
ordering(A, B, C) :-
   between(0, 100, A),  % A is an integer in the range [0,100]
   between(0, 100, B),  % same for B
   between(0, 100, C),  % and C
   A > B,
   B > C,
   A > 0,
   10 > C.
```

Sample run:

```
?- ordering(3,X,1).
X = 2 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not surprising.

Evidently `integer(X)` with `X` unbound will immediately fail. It is very "imperative" in that regard.

Additionally, the predicate will fail with `C` unbound because of `10 > C`.

At best you could write a predicate `can_be/2` so that `can_be(integer,X)` succeeds when the unbound variable `X` "can still become an integer" and fails otherwise.

By extension there would be a `can_be_ordered(A, B, C)`, which fails if it is sure that `[A,B,C]` can never be ordered due to the values they already denote, or succeeds if `[A,B,C]` can still be ordered depending on what values any unbound variables therein take on in the future.

It would be even better to reify the truth value:

`ordering(List,Result)`

where `Result` is

- `true`: Yup, ordered and will stay ordered.
- `false`: Definitely not ordered, and that won't change.
- `unknown/maybe`: There is no clear evidence that it is unordered or ordered.

Then you can also attach `ordering(List,Result)` to the unbound variables that re-checks the ordering whenever one of the variables becomes bound, using `freeze/2`. That's basically doing the work of CLP(FD).

Answer (score 1):

You could delay the comparison until the variables are initialized:

```
ordering(A, B, C) :-
    greater(A, B),
    greater(B, C).

greater(X, Y) :-
    when((nonvar(X), nonvar(Y)), X > Y).
```

Tests:

```
?- greater(3, 2).
true.

?- ordering(3, 2, 1).
true.

?- ordering(3, 2, 2).
false.

?- ordering(3, X, 1).
when(nonvar(X), 3>X),
when(nonvar(X), X>1).
```

Comment: Why not add a condition for `greater(A, C).`, too? "Fail early" shouldn't we?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer a sufficiently smart CLP should figure it out on its own.

Comment: Possibly, but here we are being direct, using `when/2` triggered by `nonvar/1`. I won't bet on the compiler being this level of smart. 